# MvxCollectionViewSource DequeueReusableCell

Tags: mvvmcross

We have set-up our collectionviewSource and a collectionview but are having performance  issues when scrolling. We currently manage the cell like this:

```
    public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var to = base.GetCell(collectionView, indexPath) as AnimalCell;
        to.SetParentLocation(_parent);
        return to;
    }
```

My question is does this manage dequeuing in the base class?

If not what is the best way to move this to using a standard dequeue

```
    public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell (UICollectionView collectionView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var animalCell = (AnimalCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (animalCellId, indexPath);

        var animal = animals [indexPath.Row];
        animalCell.Image = animal.Image;
        return animalCell;
    }
```

As changeing to the above code causes it to crash when I try and use the cells. Do I need change my Cell class or how the collectionview is set-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is does this manage dequeuing in the base class?

Yes, the default MvxCollectionViewSource uses this method:

```
    protected virtual UICollectionViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath,
                                                              object item)
    {
        return (UICollectionViewCell) collectionView.DequeueReusableCell(DefaultCellIdentifier, indexPath);
    }
```

from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxBaseCollectionViewSource.cs#L55

So whatever is causing the the performance issue, it's probably not the cell reuse (sorry, that may not help much - but at least it rules one out!)

Comment: Thanks Stuart, it happening with the CollectionView we worked on when you where up. I have optimised the shadows and label backgrounds and the binding is being delayed. Could it be rebinding the objects every time the cells get loaded? As commenting this out seems stop the juddering.

Comment: Can't really answer. It could be anything. It didn't used to judder? Is it one binding? Or all of them? SO comments too hard for debug analysis....